# writing linear system in matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following set of linear equations

$$a_{m+1,n}+a_{m-1,n}+m(a_{m,n+1}+a_{m,n-1})+(m^{2}+n^{2})a_{m,n}=f_{m,n}$$

Here $m$ and $n$ run from 1 to $N$, so there are $N^2$ equations for the unknowns $a_{m,n}$. Fixed boundary conditions are used such that $a_{N+1,n}=0$ etc.

I would like to solve this system numerically, and for that I need to first write it in matrix form $M a = f$. How can I programatically generate the coefficient matrix M?

EDIT
Trying to follow @Wolfgang's suggestion

Ok, so lets take the simplest case of N=2. Writing the equations by hand and extracting the coefficients results in the matrix equation

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
2 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 5 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 5 & 2\\
0 & 1 & 2 & 8
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
a_{1,1}\\
a_{1,2}\\
a_{2,1}\\
a_{2,2}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
f_{1,1}\\
f_{1,2}\\
f_{2,1}\\
f_{2,2}
\end{array}\right]$$

Now if I follow @Wolfgang's suggestion and replace $(m,n)$ by $i$ I get a different matrix

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
5 & 1 & 2 & 0\\
1 & 5 & 1 & 1\\
2 & 1 & 8 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 10
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
a_{1}\\
a_{2}\\
a_{3}\\
a_{4}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
f_{1}\\
f_{2}\\
f_{3}\\
f_{4}
\end{array}\right]$$

Comment: Minor nitpick: *I would like to solve this system numerically, and for that I need to first write it in matrix form* -- no, you don't *need* to do it. There are very popular [matrix-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix-free_methods) methods, which are often the best choice for large-scale systems.

Comment: I've edited my answer in response to Andy Terrel's comment as pointed out below my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-enumerate your degrees of freedom. Right now, you have two indices $1\le m,n\le N$. These span a rectangular array. Enumerate them from $i=0$ to $N^2-1$ (it turns out that zero-based indexing is so much simpler), for example by defining $i(m,n)=(m-1)+N*(n-1)$. In your case, this would corresponding to row-wise numbering. You can recover the original indices by observing that $m=(i\%N)+1$ and $n=(i/N)+1$ where the two operations are done in integer arithmetic. Then you can substitute these definitions in your formula everywhere.

Specifically, if you write your linear system in terms of $a_i$, not $a_{m,n}$, then you'll get this set of equations:
$$
  a_{i+1}+a_{i-1}+(i\%N+1)(a_{i+N}+a_{i-N})+((i\%N+1)^2+(i/N+1)^2)a_i = f_i
$$
where I've again assumed that you do the operations $i\%N$ and $i/N$ in integer arithmetic.

This is the equation you have for $i=0,\ldots,N^2$. Now write each of these $N^2$ equations down one by one and you get the corresponding matrix entries.

Comment: I still don't see how I can get the matrix form of the linear system from this..

Comment: @Andrei, Wolfgang has written the general form of the $i^{\rm th}$ row of the matrix. So if you take $i$ from 1 to $N^2$, you get the coefficients of the matrix on each row.

Comment: I moved my comment to the original question, due to lack of space here.

Comment: Not quite. The entries in $M_{1,2},M_{2,1},M_{3,4},M_{4,3}$ should be 1, if I read your formula correctly.

Comment: If you define $i$ as $m+Nn$ then it runs from $N+1$ to $N(N+1)$ as $m$ and $n$ run from 1 to $N$, and not $1$ to $N^2$. Furthermore, I still cannot recover the matrix $M$ obtained by manual substitution.

Comment: Good point, Andy. I've fixed the issues by simply reverting to zero-based indexing.